# Why can't module access attributes declared in __init__.py of its package?

Tags: python, module, package

I have a package structure as follows:

```
mypackage
  __init__.py
  mymodule.py
```

I put some "constant" declarations in `__init__.py` for example:

```
DELIMITER='\x01'
```

However, the code in the *mymodule.py* can't access DELIMITER unless I add:

```
from __init__ import *
```

To the top of the *mymodule.py* file.  I suppose I missed a concept here.  Is it that whatever is declared in `__init__.py` doesn't get read into memory until it is accessed via an import statement?  Also, is this a typical type of thing to put into the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Where did you get the impression it would work without the `import` statement?

Comment: @DavidRobinson: From the Python documentation.  ["__init__.py      Initialize the sound package"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Not sure how else I would interpret what they are saying there, other than by assuming that code in __init__.py is initialized by Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python *does* run the code in `__init__.py` when the package is imported, which allows some initialization to be done. However, just because it is run does not mean that you have access to the variables in it from within other modules.

For example:

```
testpackage
    __init__.py
    testmod.py
```

Let's say `__init__.py` has the code `print "Initializing __init__"`, and `testmod.py` has `print "Initializing testmod"`. In that case, importing `testpackage` or `testmod` would cause the initialization code to be run:

```
dynamic-oit-vapornet-c-499:test dgrtwo$ python -c "import testpackage"
Initializing __init__
dynamic-oit-vapornet-c-499:test dgrtwo$ python -c "from testpackage import testmod"
Initializing __init__
Initializing testmod
```

It *doesn't*, however, give `testmod.py` access to the variables from `__init__.py`. This has to be done explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.  You never know what is magic and what is not until you've tried it once.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Packages don't somehow roll together all of the modules in them. There's no reason for stuff in `__init__` to be accessible in the other modules unless you import it.